# Increase performance of kotlin SQLite using PRAGMA commands

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I try to create and connect to SQLite database in Kotlin using jetbrains.exposed library.

```
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SchemaUtils
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.TransactionManager
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction

private fun provideSqliteDatabase(databaseConfig: DatabaseConfig?): Database {
    val path = databaseConfig?.url ?: "./"
    File(path).mkdirs()

    logger.info("SQLite Database path: $path/database.db")
    return Database.connect("jdbc:sqlite:$path/database.db", "org.sqlite.JDBC")
        .apply {
            TransactionManager.manager.defaultIsolationLevel =
                Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED
            provideTables()

        }
}
```

I try to increase the performance of my database using some PRAGMA SQLite commands.
How can I set these configurations such as set JOURNAL_MODE:

```
PRAGMA JOURNAL_MODE='OFF';
```

Point: I run my program on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to extend your connection url with `journal_mode=OFF`.
If you'll check [SQLite driver tests](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/ada2b147dc858ef557a995e2f4ef25f7c65fc6a7/src/test/java/org/sqlite/ConnectionTest.java#L317) you will find that it parses and executes such parameters automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll have to write plain SQL in this case:

```kotlin
transaction {
    exec("PRAGMA JOURNAL_MODE='OFF'", explicitStatementType = StatementType.EXEC)
}
```